# I want to get location updates every min

Tags: android, timer, gps, location, handler

i want to get current location in every 1 minute interval, to do this i am using Timer class and implementing location fetching in it but the control is not going in Timer block dont know why,
i tried many codes but i am facing problem everytime,

i used this below code,

there is no error and no output,
it seems control is not going into desired code block.

will anyone please help me what's wrong with my code

```
public class location3 extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;
    Timer timer;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {       
                    try {
                                             //your method here
                        getLocation();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 10000); //execute in every 1 minute
 }


public void getLocation(){

   locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
              locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
              LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,1000,0,location3.this);
      location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
      double lat=location.getLatitude();
      double lon=location.getLongitude();
      Toast.makeText(location3.this, lat+","+lon, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location){}
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

Comment: is this Android in Eclipse? Might want to add those tags if so.

Comment: yes, its android in eclipse

Comment: So if you put a break point on the `timer.schedule` line it never hits the break point?